# How to find the intersection between two matrix array in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, data-analysis, tensor, ragged

```
return tf.sets.intersection(set_1,set_2)
```

I got the error message with

```
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()
```

my set_1 and set_2's type is as following

```
> set_1-> <tf.RaggedTensor [[0.1733333319425583, 0.2866666615009308,
> 1.5666667222976685, 1.3966666460037231], [0.5233333110809326, 0.1433333307504654, 0.9599999785423279, 0.5533333420753479]]>
> 
> set_2-> tf.Tensor( [[-0.03684211 -0.03684211  0.06315789  0.06315789] 
> [-0.05755278 -0.05755278  0.08386857  0.08386857]  [-0.05755278
> -0.02219744  0.08386857  0.04851323]  ...  [ 0.          0.          1.          1.        ]  [-0.1363961   0.18180195  1.1363961   0.81819805]  [ 0.18180195 -0.1363961   0.81819805  1.1363961 ]], shape=(8732, 4), dtype=float64) set1-> <tf.RaggedTensor
> [[0.1733333319425583, 0.2866666615009308, 1.5666667222976685,
> 1.3966666460037231], [0.5233333110809326, 0.1433333307504654, 0.9599999785423279, 0.5533333420753479]]> set_2-> tf.Tensor( [[-0.03684211 -0.03684211  0.06315789  0.06315789]  [-0.05755278
> -0.05755278  0.08386857  0.08386857]  [-0.05755278 -0.02219744  0.08386857  0.04851323]  ...  [ 0.          0.          1.          1.        ]  [-0.1363961   0.18180195  1.1363961   0.81819805]  [ 0.18180195
> -0.1363961   0.81819805  1.1363961 ]], shape=(8732, 4), dtype=float64)
```

set_1 is ragged tensor and set_2 is tensor 
because

```
new_boxes = tf.ragged.constant(new_boxes)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images,new_boxes,labels))
```

This won't work if I did not change `new_boxes` to the `ragged_tensor` 
I want to find the intersection of tow set_1 and set_2. 
How should I fix it and how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

That operation is not supported for ragged tensors, but it works with sparse tensors, so you can just convert the ragged tensor into that with [`.to_sparse()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#to_sparse):

```py
return tf.sets.intersection(set_1.to_sparse(), set_2)
```

You could also convert it into a regular tensor with [`.to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#to_tensor), but that would be more expensive, and would also require you to find a `default_value` that does not appear in the data.